# Creating Cell names in expanding table HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a javascript function making a table expand. I want to be able to retrieve the values of each cell. But I am struggling to find a way to call them.

```
function createTable(){
  var rows=document.getElementById('mRows').value;
  var columns=document.getElementById('nColumns').value;
  var theader = '<table id="matrixA" border="1">\n';
  var tbody='';

  for(var i=0;i<rows;i++){
    tbody+='<tr>'
    for(var j=0;j<columns;j++){
        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += '<input name="i,j">';
        tbody += '</td>';

    }
    tbody+='</tr>\n'
  }
  var tfooter='</table>'
  document.getElementById('matrix').innerHTML = theader+tbody+tfooter;
```

}

Comment: Please also provide your HTML

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this is as follows:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

cells will now be an array of all your td's

It may be easier working with the td's in each row.  You can try something like:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

 for(var i = 0;i<rows.length;i++){
     var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
```

now cells contains just the td's of the ith tr,

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve value of each cell like this:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("td")].forEach((td)=>{console.log(td.innerHTML);});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```